# Reading delimited files in C++

Tags: c++, open-source, csv

What is the best way to read in a tab delimited file in C++ and store each line as a record?  I have been looking for an open source library to help with this, but have been unsuccessful so it looks like I will have to write my own.

Comment: I was amazed that when I searched for this, I was unable to simply pluck some code from somewhere for such a simple thing. Anyway, I wrote a blog for my solution (based on other answers on Stack Exchange) [C++ Tidbits](http://goo.gl/y0bOVv)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
typedef vector<vector<string> > Rows;
Rows rows;
ifstream input("filename.csv");
char const row_delim = '\n';
char const field_delim = '\t';
for (string row; getline(input, row, row_delim); ) {
  rows.push_back(Rows::value_type());
  istringstream ss(row);
  for (string field; getline(ss, field, field_delim); ) {
    rows.back().push_back(field);
  }
}
```

This will get you started. It doesn't do any checking that each row has the same number of fields, allow for escaping `field_delim`, etc.

Comment: this code does bot work in visual studio.
the error is error "C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed".

I have included string.h

Comment: Code compiles fine on CentOS with g++. Not sure what you didn't add in to make it work

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem in using iostreams - you could read each line with getline into string, and then use stringstream on that string to iterate over fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries listed in wikipedia's article [CSV_application_support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV_application_support).